# Is there an easy way to figure out which DLCs have you bought already?

Tags: steam

Assume you bought a game on steam and 7 out of 10 DLCs that are available for that game. When you go (in the steam application) to "LIBRARY" -> "game XY" -> "DLC", you get a list of all DLCs that are available for the game XY but none of the DLCs are marked as bought or not... (?!) At least I don't see any marks. If you click on a specific DLC though, you get "You already own XY", or the "Buy XY" depending on having/not having the DLC.

Is there an easier way to find out which DLCs you are missing than clicking to each DLC? Perhaps a place (that I haven't found yet) with a list of all the DLCs available for that game and some small icons that would tell you if you have that DLC or not?

I am asking because if a game has lots of DLCs, it is a bit tiresome to click and check all of them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of the [Steam Discovery Update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/14478/) on Sept. 23rd, 2014, Steam itself now shows you the DLC you own in the Store page without having to use browser extensions or look at the game properties in your library.

The blue markings on the left side of each DLC entry indicate that I own it already and if I hover over it, there will be a popout that shows that it's in my library.

[image: Steam DLC list]

Note that isn't perfect. In this particular example, Steam shows that I don't own Wonders of the Ancient World, even though I do, but I'm guessing that's a problem with that particular piece of DLC, as it's done that since release. However, Steam still won't let you buy anything you already own, so you're safe from double purchases.

Comment: thnx. I hope they make it better and more intuitive than this..

Comment: Just tried that for Magicka. The "Party Robes" DLC was shown as not owned, but on its page was a green "you already own this" banner. So be sure to recheck "not owned items".

Comment: I use this method myself and have for some time. The downside is when the packages get messed up. Then Steam won't list you owning that item, but when you try to buy it again, Steam will reject the buy for self order. But this is the best system I've found so far.

Answer (score 13):

Steam has now implemented a menu to allow you to view the collection of DLC you own.

Right click the item in your library, and select the "View Downloadable Content" option:
[image: View Downloadable Content]

This will bring up a window in the game's options, listing the DLC you have purchased for the game:
[image: DLC List]

Comment: thnx, +1. although the answer FAE provided gives a bit more info - you can know which DLC's are still out there that you don't have more easily.

Comment: @pootzko This is actually the same information that TylerShads has provided in his answer below, as he did mention the menu option.

Answer (score 5):

Others already stated the direct and true answer. Let me tell you about a plugin that makes these steps obsolete.

With **[Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/)**, a browser plugin, you can see which games you already bought (or have in wishlist) while browsing the Steam store. While in a list of games, all bought games and/or DLCs are coloured green so you can easily see what you already have got.

It has also more features, like comparing prices in other regions, listing sales for a product or warning of 3rd person DRM. You can see this in the [features list](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/features.php).

It is one of my favourite plugins, as it really enhances my experience on the Steam website.

Here is an example of some DLCs the guy already bought:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best thing I could find is by logging into steam [**though their website**](https://store.steampowered.com/account/) And go to your account information.

There you can see all of the items you have purchased in the past, including DLC.

As far as the actual Steam Client goes, the best you can do is right click on each game that you have and select *"View Downloadable Content"* but that is not as comprehensive of a list as going to the website is.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Chrome extension called "Enhanced Steam." This will highlight games and DLC you already own in green. It only works on the web version of the store. It will also highlight if you have a copy of a game in your inventory, if any of your friends have it on their wishlist, what price its selling for elsewhere, etc.

Comment: That looks quite interesting.

Comment: it also exists for FF.